# PHP move_uploaded_file fail

Tags: php, ios, alamofire

I am trying to upload an image through alamofire and I have done it! My server received it but when I call move_uploaded_file function in my php file it shows FAILURE. I am sure that my server received the image and i am able to create directories through php. It is just this move_uploaded_file not letting me do the job. Here is my php code:

```
<?php

if (empty($_FILES["image"])){
    $response = array("error" => "no data");
}else{


        $path = "./Upload";
        if(!file_exists($path)){
            mkdir($path,0777,true);
            $response["message"] = "new file created";
        }else{
            $response["message"] = "file already exist";
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],$path)){
                $response["message"] = "You've got it!!!";
            }else{
                $response["message"] = "upload function fail";
            }
        }
    }


echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: $path is a directory, not a file

Answer (score 0):

$path is a directory, not a file. Change it to:

```
$path = "./Upload/file.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change:**

```
$path = "./Upload";
```

**With:**

```
$path= "uploads/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```